# ERROR: Received close_notify during handshake

Tags: android, android-studio, sslhandshakeexception

I have updated my Android Studio to 3.5.3, I am getting error after creating new project, I could not figure out what is the exact issue with it. I am using Kotlin as a programming language.

Is it because of newer version of Android Studio ?

ERROR: Received close_notify during handshake

Comment: HI @Aditya Vyas-Lakhan, what is your java version?

Comment: It is Java 8 I am using

Comment: close_notify corresponds to ssl, it's there in java 8...some times it may occur due to service block (your antivirus or defender is not allow). Once please check whether that.

Comment: You mean to say I need to block my antivirus for sometime?

Comment: yes antivirus as well as windows defender (if yours windows PC)